# fix time tolerance of video frames

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am getting frames with an IObservable. Frames reception have tolerance of 1-100ms. I want to raise each Frame with constant delay of 30ms. How can I do it in Reactive Extensions?

Comment: I'm not following your issue. Are you just asking for `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30.0))`?

Comment: I have an `IObservable<Frame>` which throw events with tolerance of 1-100ms, how can I re-schedule all the events so they will be raised exactly every 30ms. I thought of buffering and than re-throwing, but didn't find how to do it

Comment: Well, that now depends. `IObservable<IList<T>> query = source.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30.0));` is possibly what you need. So is `IObservable<T> query = source.Zip(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30.0)), (x, _) => x);`. Can you provide more detail as to what you need?